# Which Operating Ontario Parks lack gatekeepers?

Tags: ontario, parks-and-gardens

This question excludes NON-Operating Parks (because they obviously lack gatekeepers) that I deselected in [the map](https://www.ontarioparks.com/park-locator#).

My overly anxious grandparents (of age 77 and 75) prefer visiting and camping at Operating Parks (henceforth OOP) that are monitored and have gatekeepers. But the linked map above fails to communicate this:  at some OOP (found with that link, but whose name they forgot), they discovered no gatekeeper; instead the gate was open and a donation box was left instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe this is going to be a fixed list. Whether or not the gate is manned (no sexism intended) will probably vary with time and day, and will depend on the expected level of business and available staff. A gatekeeper won't add a whole lot to security. Even at the busiest parks there will be no gatekeeper at night, and many parks allow day access so there is no way to exclude people.

Obviously larger and busier parks will have more staff, and remote ones fewer.